# Unrecognized prop on DOM element when passing it into MUI styled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

running into an issue where I'm trying to pass a prop into an MUI styled component but recieving this error when running the test suite.

> ```
> Warning: React does not recognize the `charNumber` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `charnumber` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
> ```

```
styled component: 

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)<{ $charNumber: number }>(
  ({ charNumber, theme }) => ({
    borderWidth: '2px',
    ...textAreaStyling(theme as Theme, charNumber),
  })
);
```

When I call this styled component and give it the charNumber prop (a useState that keeps track of maxLength - typed characters ) I get the above error

```
where its called: 

<Box>
   <StyledTextField
      charNumber={charNumber}
      error={error}
      multiline
      onChange={handleOnChange}
      inputProps={{ ...inputProps }}
      {...props}
    />
  </Box>
```

Any ideas on how to remove this error from occuring inside the test suite?